# Intervals in measure theory

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am going through Rosenthal's A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory but I am stuck on one particular part. On page 9, when constructing the uniform distribution, he says

> It seems clear that we should choose $\Omega = [0,1]$. But what about $\mathcal{F}$? We know from proposition 1.2.6 that $\mathcal{F}$ cannot contain all intervals of $\Omega$, but it should certainly contain all the intervals $[a,b],[a,b)$, etc. That is, we must have $\mathcal{J} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$, where $\mathcal{J} = \{\textrm{all intervals contained in [0,1]}\}$

I am confused when he says that $\mathcal{F}$ cannot contain all intervals of $\Omega$, yet must contain all intervals contained in $\Omega$. What exactly are the intervals that are not contained in the set $\mathcal{J}$, but are in the set of all intervals of $\Omega$?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know what version of the book you have. But in my most recent version, it says $\mathcal{F}$ cannot contain **all subsets** of $\Omega$ NOT intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are working with the first printing, there is an errata correcting that mistake that can be found [here](http://www.probability.ca/jeff/ftpdir/errata2.pdf). It should say that due to proposition $1.2.6$, that $\mathcal{F}$ can not contain all subset of $\Omega$, but it should contain all intervals.